# Assign User Points in existing website which already contains content

Tags: users, userpoints, rating, 7

Question specific to "User Points" module, backcopy of question from here due to no response: https://www.drupal.org/node/2492933

Drupal 7 -

I have a website which is already running for more than 2 years. Many users have been adding content to it and now I have a requirement where I need to assign points to the user. I came across [this great module](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) but this does not let me assign values to the user based on the content they have already contributed, revisions already worked on and also the comments provided already.

I have tried to google and also checked the module thoroughly but there is no way to do what I want to achieve. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [User Points Contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) and I provided a patch with which points are awarded for nodes and revisions in past and also the points transactions are stored across with the dates on which the node was created or revision was made.

Issue and patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1187616#comment-10004999

Answer (score 1):

I think [User Points Contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) is your best alternative available today. I. e. submodule **userpoints_retroactive**. Excerpt from that project page:

> Award users points for their nodes, comments and votes that they have created so far, before userpoints was enabled on the site.

However, the [port of this module to D7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1963542) still **needs work**. Maybe you can/want to somehow contriute to the finishing touch of that issue?

PS: there is also [Berdir's Api documentation](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints_contrib-7.x-1.x!userpoints_retroactive!userpoints_retroactive.module/7-1) about this submodule ... (maybe that helps somehow).

Comment: Thank you, good find. Will wait and see if there are any other answers / possibilities, if not I will try the same.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I have ported the module and I provided enhancements to the contributed modules.